# Proof that this distribution is N(0,1)?

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

I'm having trouble with this question.

> Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from some distribution with mean $\mu_1$ and variance $\sigma_1^2>0$. Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ be a random sample from some other completely unrelated distribution with mean $\mu_2$ and variance $\sigma_2^2>0$. Prove that as $n \to \infty$,
>   $$
> Z_n
>  = \frac{(\bar{X}_n - \bar{Y}_n) - (\mu_1-\mu_2)}
>          {\sqrt{\left(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 \right)}/n}
>  \to \mathcal{N}(0,1).
> $$

The fact that I don't know the distribution of $X_i$ and $Y_i$ throws me off. Does the CLT always go to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define $A_n = X_n - Y_n$ then you don't know the distribution of $A_n$ but its mean is $\mu_A = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ and its variance is $\sigma_A^2 = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$ since $X$ and $Y$ are unrelated (i.e. independent) processes.

Hence,
$$
Z_n = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n A_n - \mu_A}{\sigma_A/n}
$$

and you can apply the CLT.

Comment: Does the CLT always have a distribution of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?, so since we can apply the CLT, we can conclude that this distribution is also $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Comment: @user270494 depends on the form. In the most common form for a stochastic process $Z_n$ with mean $m$ and stdev $s$, we have $$\frac{\bar{Z}_n - m}{s/n} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

Comment: So since we can write it in that form, then $Z_n$ -> $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Comment: @user270494 yes